# how to send firebase push notification from one device to all installed devices using Xamarin.android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Hi I have enbaled firebase push notification to my app. It can receive FCM cloud message from https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project. But I want to send notification from one installed device to all other devices using xamarin.android. Say for example I have one textbox for title and another for body and a button. When I will click button then it will send push notification to all devices.Plese tell all the steps. Will be very helpful.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store all the tokens for the devices registered in a database and then send notifications to all the tokens at once. Note that your token must be a list of string stored in as registration_ids.

Answer (score 0):

you can also used postman to send push notification on behalf of token. Please try below link
https://mobikul.com/send-push-notification-via-firebase-ios-postman/